# What are elements a,b such that each has prime power degree but their product does not?

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

I am studying from Artin and this is a practice problem I've come across.

For prime $p$, suppose there is an element $\alpha$ with degree $p^n$ over $\mathbb Q$ and an element $\beta$ with degree $p^m$ over $\mathbb Q$. Prove or find a counterexample for the following claim: the degree of $\alpha\beta$ must be a power of $p$.

I have not done Galois theory, and I have tried $\sqrt[3]{2}$ and $\omega$ which is the primitive root of unity of $x^3-1$. I think this is close, but I'm not sure.

Comment: What is the minimal polynomial of $ab=\sqrt[3]{2}\omega$ over $\Bbb Q$? Why should its degree not be of the form $p^k=3^k$? Can you copy the exact wording of the exercise?

Comment: I've edited the question, hopefully it's more clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\alpha = \sqrt[3]{2}$ and $\beta = \omega/\sqrt[3]{2}$. Both have degree $3$ over $\mathbf Q$ while their product $\omega$ has degree $2$ over $\mathbf Q$.

More generally, let $\alpha = \sqrt[n]{2}$ and $\beta = e^{2\pi i/n}/\sqrt[n]{2}$, so $\alpha$ and $\beta$ have degree $n$ over $\mathbf Q$ while $\alpha\beta = e^{2\pi i/n}$, which has degree $\varphi(n)$ over $\mathbf Q$. When $n$ is a power of a prime $p$, $\varphi(n)$ is divisible by $p-1$, so when $n$ is an *odd* prime power, $\varphi(n)$ is not a power of $p$.

Answer (score 0):

Try $2^{1/3}(1+\omega)$.

Let $\alpha=2^{1/3}(1+\omega)$. $\newcommand{\rat}{\mathbb{Q}}$
Let $\beta=2^{1/3}$.
Let $K=\rat(\beta,\omega)$.
We know that $[K:\rat]=6$.
By a simple calculation,
we see that $K=\rat(\omega,\alpha)$.
In particular, we have $[\rat(\omega,\alpha):\rat(\omega)]=3$,
so $\alpha$ has degree $3$ over $\rat(\omega)$.
Now, $f:=x^3-2(1+\omega)$ is a polynomial over $\rat(\omega)$
that vanishes $\alpha$,
but $\alpha$ has degree $3$,
so $f$ is irreducible over $\rat(\omega)$.
Then it divides the minimal polynomial $g$ of $\alpha$ over $\rat$,
so $g$ must have a degree above $3$ because $f\not\in\rat[x]$.
It can only be the case that $\deg(g)=6$ because $[K:\rat]=6$.